# besides those two

Tags: meaning

a. I know Dr. Jones has recommended that you read 'Light in August' and 'Absalom, Absalom'. I would like to recommend another book.

b. I know Dr. Jones has recommended that you read 'Light in August' and 'Absalom, Absalom'. I would like to recommend another book as well.

c. I know Dr. Jones has recommended that you read 'Light in August' and 'Absalom, Absalom'. I would like to recommend another book besides those two.

Do these imply that the speaker is recommending 'Light in August' and 'Absalom, Absalom'? Or could they be used if the speaker has no idea about those books, does not like them etc.?

My feeling is that in (a) the speaker is non-committal as to the two books mentioned. He is saying neither that he likes nor that he dislikes them. In (b) and (c) he seems to me to be endorsing the two books. He is recommending them. He is also recommending another one. That is how I feel about the sentences. But I have doubts!!

Many thanks.

Comment: A and C are ambiguous.

Comment: They're *all* "ambiguous". It's entirely a matter of interpretation / context whether one associates ***another, as well, besides*** with the ***books*** or with the ***recommendations***.

Answer (score -1):

I think sentence (a) is perfectly all right, it does imply you recommending an additional book. However, you could stress that you really recommend a third book by saying

> In addition (to those two) I would like to recommend another book.